# Simple javascript can't figure out where it's wrong

Tags: javascript

i can't figure out where I went wrong with this simple javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
<script>
   function changeColor() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
        if (elem.style.color == black) {
            elem.style.color = blue
        }
        else if (elem.style.color == blue) {
            elem.style.color = red
        }
        else if (elem.style.color == red) {
            elem.style.color = black
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="para1"> Some text here</p>
    <button onclick='changeColor();'>Change!</button>
    <!-- <button onclick='changeColor("red");'>red</button> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Realise debugging is much harder with javascript than VBA - that i'm used it.

Comment: `black` and other literals should be enclosed in quotation marks, i.e., `"black"`.

Comment: Ohhhhh.............. I have no other words. And vote to close. As too localized. Sorry.

Comment: How is debugging in JavaScript much harder? It couldn't be easier... Chrome Developer Tools (available when pressing F12) and FireBug do a great bit in it and allow the use of `console.log` anywhere in your code, even dumping objects and errors. What could you possibly want more? Except for step-by-step debugging, of course...

Comment: *"Realise debugging is much harder with javascript than VBA"* Nonsense. Every modern browser has a reasonably-featured debugger built into it, some of them quite good. In 2004 debugging client-side JavaScript was a pain. Not in 2013.

Comment: @Derija93: *"What could you possibly want more? Except for step-by-step debugging, of course..."* Huh? Chrome's dev tools (and Safari's, and IE's, and Opera's, and Firefox either with or without Firebug) allows you to step through code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Really? Well I never new that. So indeed there is nothing more you could want. (I should do some research on that, thanks!)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks but Brad got the first answer, though i should have worded the question clearer.

Comment: @user2135737: Just be careful to test on all of the browsers you intend to support. Brad's quite right in terms of *setting* the value, but you can't rely on what you get back when comparing later (cross-browser).

Comment: Alright guys, i've put the ' ' in but the color switches only once. From 'black' to 'blue' and it stops there. What about switching to 'red' and 'black' when i keep clicking the button?

Comment: @VisioN and all, Would you all consider closing this as "too localised"? My example was extracted off Mozilla Developer Network as one of the samples. I would think it's quite widespread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your color values.

```
elem.style.color = 'red';
```

Comment: That said, it's frequently the case that the string you get back from `style.color` when comparing isn't `"black"` or `"red"` but `"rgb(0, 0, 0)"` or `"rgb(255, 0, 0)"` (and it varies from browser to browser).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Interesting... I had assumed you would get back whatever was previously set.  Good to know!

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems.

The first is the one that everyone has pointed out, you should be using strings when assigning color values e.g.:

```
elem.style.color = "black";
```

But the second is more subtle. The string you get back from `elem.style.color` is **not** reliably `"black"` or `"blue"`, etc., even if that's what you've assigned. It can be `"rgb(0,0,0)"` or similar.

For that reason, you need to track the "current" color separately, like this:

```
function changeColor() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
    var color = elem.getAttribute("data-color");
    if (!color || color == "black") {
        color = elem.style.color = "blue";
    }
    else if (color == "blue") {
        color = elem.style.color = "red";
    }
    else if (color == "red") {
        color = elem.style.color = "black";
    }
    elem.setAttribute("data-color", color);
}
```

There, I've used a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) to track the color I've assigned to the element, in a way that I know won't be converted into an RGB value. (And I've also used strings, rather than variable names, for things like `"black"` and `"blue"` and such.)

Comment: And finally one undefined `black` ran away from your

Comment: Thanks TJ Crowder! Javascript has more intricacies than VBA indeed! This is seriously good information! And I've just picked out a simple example (thought it was simple) from Mozilla DN!

Answer (score -1):

Without quotes they are read as variables, add the quotes for check these as strings

```
var elem = document.getElementById("para1");
    switch(elem.style.color){
       case 'black':
                elem.style.color = 'blue'
                break;
       case 'blue':
                elem.style.color = 'red';
                break;
       case 'red':
                elem.style.color = 'black';
                break;
    }
```

Comment: The thing is, you don't necessarily get back what you set. You might set `"black"` but when reading it later get back `"rbg(0,0,0)"` or similar.

Comment: Hey sam, I tried your code but it didn't work on my web browser firefox.